# Horizontally split-screen with two programs?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, gnu-screen, split-window

I have two programs A and B. I want a single command, which will run Program A and Program B in two different terminals but in the same tab, i.e, in a horizontally split terminal. I know screen can do that but I have to manually enter C-a S, C-a tab, C-a c to invoke, switch and run the programs. If I want to do so in a single command, is it possible?

Comment: You can set up a simple `.screenrc` file to automatically create the sub-windows and execute the commands for you.

Comment: you could use [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) terminal which supports split shells in the same tab, and sending keystrokes to multiple split shells at the same time

Comment: @twalberg I know about the .screenrc file. But I don't know the command to do so. Could you please provide a sample for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `.screenrc` to accomplish this might look something like this:

```
# whatever other normal entries you have for options and other configuration
sessionname some_descriptive_name
screen 0 first_command
split
focus down
screen 1 second_command
```

That splits the screen vertically, though... Not sure how to split horizontally, but I'll update later if I figure it out...

Edit: use `split -v` to split horizontally (the split line is vertical, so you have left/right instead of top/bottom).

Answer (score -1):

iTerm can do that with a shell command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).